# remove circle recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha

I am using recaptcha for the registration page in my website got from recaptcha.net. I feel difficult to read the two word that is generating automatically. I want to remove the dark circl at the back ground of the text or else single word to type easily.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Recaptcha is constantly evolving and the image distortion algorithm changes every once in a while to keep fooling bots. They used to draw a line though the word a while back, then they used very little obfuscation, now they have circles. The whole point of a Captcha is to obfuscate text, so yes, it is hard to read sometimes.

[Here](http://recaptcha.net/apidocs/captcha/client.html)'s a list of things you can customize. Using another obfuscation algorithm is not among the options. So there's not much you can do about it besides using a different Captcha.

Answer (score 0):

I feel for you, there has been severe inflation in the level of distortion of the images in some popular Captcha solutions the last 1-2 years. If it has to be human-unreadable to be bot-unreadable you have to ask yourself if it was a good solution to start with.

reCaptcha certainly is often not very user-friendly.

Look for a better solution such as identify-the-symbol or the question/answer ones. The latter works great for special-interest sites as you can provide some questions new users should know the answer to!